# Why takeWhile does not delivery values

Tags: f#

I have the following code snippet:

```
let t = seq { 1..10 } |> Seq.takeWhile (fun e -> e % 2 = 0)
t |> Seq.iter( fun e -> printf "%A " e)
```

And t does not contain any values but I am expecting 2,4,6 and 8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Seq.takeWhile` stops processing as soon as it finds a value that makes the predicate return `false`. You may need `Seq.filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Seq.filter` instead of `Seq.takeWhile`. `Seq.takeWhile` stop processing as soon as the predicate returns `false` and because `false` is returned on the 1 there is no elements further.

From MSDN:

> Returns a sequence that, when iterated, yields elements of the underlying sequence while the given predicate returns **true**, **and then returns no further elements**.

```
seq { 1..10 } 
|> Seq.filter (fun e -> e % 2 = 0)
|> Seq.iter( fun e -> printf "%A " e)
```

Note: No need to bind it to `t` as `Seq.iter` yields no elements, just `unit`